# Autoredirect within my blog - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have an existing wordpress blog with some posts. But now im planning to move my blog to a sub domain. Now i want to redirect my visitors to my sub domain.

For example if a user types

`www.mysite.com/2011/07/posts.html`

then he should be automatically redirected to

`www.blog.mysite.com/2011/07/posts.html`.

Is there any plugin to help out me? Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this plugin to resolve my issue.

[Redirection plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/)